# How do I remove node URLs?

Tags: nodes, 6

I have path aliasing, which gets the path from the title of the *News* article, working fine.

However, in the Google index, I noticed that the canonical URL for nodes is working as well. So, Google is indexing the node pages twice: with the canonical URL and with the path alias.

I want to disable the canonical URL for nodes, so I tried installing the node_page_disable module.  It installed fine, and I enabled it with Drupal 6.

In http://www.example.com/admin/settings/site-information, there is a  *Default front page* textbox, which by default contains *node*. If I remove *node* from the textbox, and save the settings, Drupal complains with:

> Default front page field is required.

The module I installed adds a *Retain /node as an active url?* checkbox.
If I click on that, I am required to remove *node* from the *Default front page* textbox.

How can I do it, since removing *node* causes Drupal to complain about a required value not given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I used the Global redirect module to fix this. Here is the guide:

http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3571/solved-drupal-pathauto-google-is-indexing-node-urls-instead-of-url-aliases

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must give a value for *Default front page*, and since you don't want to use *node*, you need to give another value for that setting.

- Enable the Path module that comes with Drupal 6 core, from admin/build/modules

  > [image: screenshot]
- Create a *Page* node, from node/add

  > [image: screenshot]
- Add the path alias you want to use to the node being created

  > [image: screenshot]
- Save it
- Change the default front page, and put the path alias you assigned to the node you just created, on admin/settings/site-information

  > [image: screenshot]
- Save the settings

Now Drupal will use that node as front page.

> [image: screenshot]

If you installed the *Vertical tabs* module, the node edit page would appear different. In this case, you can find the path alias text-box under the *URL path settings* tab.

> [image: screenshot]

I used a *Page* node for the front page, but you can use any content type you want.